# Constructing 2024 from the first 7 natural numbers

Tags: mathematics, no-computers, formation-of-numbers

Can you use each number 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 exactly once, the four operations +, -, *, / and the parentheses to construct the number 2024? **Bonus:** can you find multiple distinct solutions? No computers please.

Comment: The last 3 questions of that format where all downvoted and closed. Unless there is some clever twist on the concept, the idea of 'make this number from these digits with some basic operations' is just not that interesting.

Comment: I thought the same when I saw the title.  But unlike the other questions that requested a whole range of values which were way too easy to produce, given too many operators, this question requests a single result and the solution is far from obvious to find.  It is not the same level.

Comment: What is considered 'distinct' could use some more explanation. (e.g. is the swap Florian F suggests a distinct solution?; is 3x2 distinct from 2x3?) Now it is unclear how many distinct solutions there are.

Comment: Commutativity should not count as distinct imho.  But I had another swap in mind.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One solution would be

> $2024 = (2 + 3 \times 4 \times 6 \times 7) \times (5 - 1)$

A significantly different one is

> $2024 = (1 + (2 + 4) \times 6 \times 7) \times (3 + 5)$

Comment: There is an easy swap for a second solution.

Comment: @FlorianF I'm aware. Just not sure it should count as different.

Comment: Well done. That's the first solution. Can you find one more? The direct swap does not count.

Comment: @DmitryKamenetsky I think I found it. It's related but not trivially so.

Comment: Yes that's the one, congratulations!